# Read CSV file and write to another CSV - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and pattern difficuties

Tags: java, regex

I'm creating a java program that reads data from one csv file and saves with little changes to another csv file:

a) In 3rd column of output file I must extract only price in specific format (e.g. 4.99, 2522.78) from 4th column in input file

b) In 4th colum of otput file I must extract date in formt DD.MM.YYYY from 5th column in input file if it is.

c) The input file in the last three rows hasn't got last column. It causes when I read lines and want read first row with no last column it throws me exception.

There is a litte more, but those are difficulties to overcome. Could you help me? I have pattern but I just don't know how to use it in table like mine.

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RwCSV {

private static final String SOURCE_FILE = "/home/krystian/Pulpit/products.csv";
private static final String RESULT_FILE = "/home/krystian/Pulpit/result3.csv";
private static final String DELIMITER1 = ";";
private static final String DELIMITER2 = "|";
//Pattern pattern;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(SOURCE_FILE));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(RESULT_FILE)) {


        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(DELIMITER1);
            String[] result = new String[5];

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+.\\d\\d");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(values[3]);
            //System.out.println(values[4]);
            result[0] = "'"+values[0]+"'";
            result[1] = "'"+values[1]+"?id="+values[2]+"'";
            result[2] = "'"+values[3]+"'";
            result[3] = "'"+values[3]+"'";
            result[4] = "'"+values[4]+"'"; //throws exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                fw.write(result[i].replace("\"", ""));

                if (i != result.length - 1) {
                    fw.write(DELIMITER2);
                }

                if (values.length<5) {continue;}
            }
            fw.write("\n");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex) {

    }
}
}
```

Input file:

```
"Product Name";"Link";"SKU";"Selling-Price";"description"
"Product #1";"http://mapofmetal.com";"AT-23";"USD 1,232.99";"This field contains no date!"
"Product #2";"http://mapofmetal.com";"BU-322";"USD 8654.56";"Here a date: 20.09.2014"
"Product #3";"http://mapofmetal.com";"FFZWE";"EUR 1255,59";"Another date: 31.4.1999"
"Product #4";"http://mapofmetal.com";234234;"345,99 €";"Again no date in this field."
"Product #5";"http://mapofmetal.com";"UDMD-4";"$34.00";"Here are some special characters: öäüß"
"Product #6";"http://mapofmetal.com";"33-AAU43";"431.333,0 EUR";"American date: 12-23-2003"
"Product #7";"http://mapofmetal.com";"33-AAU44";"431.333,0 EUR";"One more date: 1.10.2014"
"Product #8";"http://mapofmetal.com";"33-AAU45";"34,99";
"Product #9";"http://mapofmetal.com";"UZ733-2";234.99;
"Product #10";"http://mapofmetal.com";"42-H2G2";42;
```

Output file row pattern (must be changed separator and quote-character):

```
'Product #2'|'http://mapofmetal.com?id=BU-322'|'8654.56'|'20.09.2014'
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: in for loop i tried if (m.find())
     fw.write(result[3]=m.group(0));

Comment: i tried too if (m.find()){result[3] = "'"+m.group(0)+"'";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### About the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Your problem seems to be that when the input ends with `;`, the 5th element gets discarded. For example:

```
"abc;def;".split(";")  ->  ["abc", "def"]
```

Instead of what you would like, `["abc", "def", ""]`

To have that effect, either pass the number elements you expect as a second parameter to `.split()`, for example:

```
"abc;def;".split(";", 3)  ->  ["abc", "def", ""]
```

Or a negative value:

```
"abc;def;".split(";", -1)  ->  ["abc", "def", ""]
```

This is explained in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

#### About extracting the price

Extracting the price is tricky because you have multiple formats:

- USD 1,232.99
- EUR 1255,59
- 345,99 €
- $34.00
- 34,99

The biggest problem there is the comma, which sometimes should be ignored, other times it's a decimal point.
Here's something that will work with the example you gave, but is likely not exhaustive, and you would need to improve on it depending on the other possible inputs you might have:

```
String price;
if (values[3].startsWith("EUR ") || values[3].endsWith(" €")) {
    // ignore non-digits and non-commas, and replace commas with dots
    price = values[3].replaceAll("[^\\d,]", "").replaceAll(",", ".");
} else {
    // ignore non-digits and non-dots
    price = values[3].replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
}
```

Then there's this format I'm not sure what to make of:

```
431.333,0 EUR
```

I think you need better specs for the input format.
It's unnecessarily hard and error-prone to work with such inconsistent input.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. What regex do you need? What doesn't work as you expect? What is the input, what is the output, and what did you expect?

Comment: like I said in a) and b) point - I don't know how to use patterns (or something similar) to extract price from 4th of input file (in format with dot separator) and extract date from 5th column of input file (in format DD.MM.YYYY). It's not something doesn't work. I tried typical pattern style and it didn't extract anything.

Comment: I added to my answer, I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long you want to use this code there are quick vs. More robust options.

An easy one is to add a try and catch around checking for a result in values [4] and then insert a default value in the catch when not present in the file.

Comment: I solved it. Now left me only problem with extracting specific vaues from strings.

Comment: Then you need to add an answer yourself or select this one as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Your products file only has 4 columns starting a "Product #8". So you are trying to access values[4] and there that array index doesn't exist.

Comment: I solved that. My only problem is to use regex to extract price and  datefrom string in specific format.